# Can't Remove White Spaces from CSV Headers with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to rename headers in a csv that have white spaces. Using these lines from the Pandas API reference is not working. The headers still have white spaces instead of underscores.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("my.csv",low_memory=False)
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_')
```

Comment: See discussion below, this is a Python 2 related question.

Answer (score 6):

Try using a list comprehension.

```
df.columns = [c.strip().lower().replace(' ', '_') for c in df.columns]
```

Comment: Strange, because I tried this with one of my dataframes and it's working here. Maybe you can re-check your code and if it still doesn't work, provide the version number of pandas & python you are using. I'm testing with python 3.6 & pandas 0.23.4

Comment: So when I just print df.columns and don't try to replace anything, I get this list (I've shortened it). The first header already has an underscore in its name. Index([u'DWH_ID', u'ID', u'Actual Retirement', u'In Service',
       u'Gross Area (Imperial)', u'Gross Area', u'Area (Imperial)',
       u'Area (Metric)', u'Area', u'Area Units'])

Comment: It also says dtype='object' at the end of the index. Could that be why string replace isn't working?

Comment: No. From the `'u'`prefix it seems you are using the outdated python2 instead of the current python3, so you may be using an outdated pandas as well. Please post your version numbers.

Comment: Yes, Python 2.7.13 from an ArcGIS install. Pandas version 0.23.4

Comment: OK, in that case you would need to find a python2 specific solution. You could try enclosing the columns `list(df.columns)` before renaming or try with `df.rename` if renaming columns works at all. 

If possible, just upgrade to python3, because you will run into a lot more problems if you stay on python2 since all support is cancelled from 2020 and pandas quits supporting it earlier.

Comment: I also have Python 3 with ArcGIS Pro. 0.23.4 is the latest version of Pandas.

Comment: Try this with python 3 then. If it still doesn't work, I suspect the spaces in your column names are not real spaces, but something that looks like a space but is differenct. Try comparing it to a space in that case, like `u'Gross Area'[5:6] == ' '` but with your variables. If this fails, I give up...

Answer (score 0):

Tried using rename?

```
df.rename(index=str, columns={"A space": "a", "B space ": "c"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I ditched Pandas and just used the CSV module in Python 2.7.

```
import csv
import re
import tempfile
import sys
import os
if sys.version_info >= (3, 3):
    from os import replace
elif sys.platform == "win32":
    from osreplace import replace
else:
    from os import rename as replace

newHeaderList = []

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir='.', delete=False) as tmp, \
    open('myFile.txt', 'rb') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t')
    w = csv.writer(tmp, delimiter = '\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    header = next(r)
    for h in header:
        headerNoSpace = re.sub("\s+", "_", h.strip())
        newHeaderList.append(headerNoSpace)
    w.writerow(newHeaderList)
    for row in r:
        w.writerow(row)

os.rename(tmp.name, new_text_filepath)


new_txt = csv.reader(open('newFile.txt', "rb"), delimiter = '\t')
out_csv = csv.writer(open('myFile.csv', 'wb'))
out_csv.writerows(new_txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read with regex as `sep` to remove all spaces in the header:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", sep='\s*&\s*')
```

here `\s` means a blank character, and `*` means match the previous expression (`\s` here) zero or any times.

I guess you are reading a file look like this

```
Name,  Age,   City
John Smith, 30, New York
Jane Doe, 25, San Francisco
Bob Johnson, 45, Los Angeles
```

or like this

```
Name        , Age , City
John Smith  , 30  , New York
Jane Doe    , 25  , San Francisco
Bob Johnson , 45  , Los Angeles
```

Both works with the code above. BUT, using regex in `sep` may slow down the reading process because 'c' engine does not support regex, so 'python' engine will be used. Be careful when reading very large file.